# Plugin for custom posts and fields

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, multisite, plugin-recommendation

I need a plugin to do the following:

- Add custom posttypes such as "Books" or "Cars"
- Add custom fields such as "Url", "Label", "Number of wheels", "Name of passenger" or "Age of passenger"

There are some requirements

1. This should work on a multisite installation and it should be possible to fetch posts and the data for that post from an other site in the multisite network
2. Some fields needs to be grouped, eg. "Name of passenger" and "Age of passenger"
3. Some fields needs to be ordered (by the user), say for instance the user want to order the group of passenger-age, so when displayed the names will show up in that order

Do you know any plugin that will do this?

Answer (score 1):

ACF - Advanced Custom Fields is the most extensive and easiest to use plugin for custom fields. For custom post types check out http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/types/ or even better http://themergency.com/generators/wordpress-custom-post-types/ for hard-coded post types.

Comment: Thanks Rezen. I've tried to plugins but I didn't manage to create a solution to point 2 and 3 in my question. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You can create "groups" by adding Add New Field Groups. ACF is already organize by group, so you just need to make sure to add separate groups. In regards to sorting, you will have to add that custom functionality since it's custom to your site. There may be a plugin, but doubtfully. If you do find one let us know!

Answer (score 1):

There is also [Easy Content Types](http://pippinsplugins.com/easy-content-types/), which does post types, taxonomies and custom fields all in one.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but what I can see it's not possible to group fields (2) and order the groups (3). Please correct me if I'm wrong. It would be perfect if it was possible for the user to repeat and move "Meta Boxes".

Comment: Hi Warwick. Welcome to the community. Thanks for posting your first answer here. I wanted to guide you to the FAQ for future reference http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion  Link only answers are not considered to be quality answers. If the link is removed on the remote host, the answer becomes benign. It's best to describe why the plugin works well for you, possibly add screen shots, and explain how to accomplish the solution using this plugin. You might also add code snippets relevant to the question to maintain the posterity of your answer for future users. :)